# список ul на сайте

Tags: html, css

Хэлоу! У меня возникла проблема со списком на моем сайте (второй элемент ul отображается как дочерний элемент первого ul):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот фрагмент кода:

```html
<div class="container_2">
      <ol>
       <ul>
           <div class="block1">
            <h4 classs="header1">The Blog Time</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p> 
           </div>
       </ul>

       <ul>
        <div class="block2">
         <h4 class="header2">Navigation</h4>
        </div>
       </ul>
      </ol>
```

контейнер2 - это окно со списком.

Comment: *второй элемент ul отображается как дочерний элемент первого ul*, но по факту он ведь не есть дочерним. проблема в стилизации

Comment: Не закрыт <div class="container_2">. div нельзя вставлять напрямую в ul и ul нельзя напрямую вставить в ol.

Comment: @Roman div закрыт был - скопировал код не до конца, а так моя ошибка сорри

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если block1 и block2 - элементы списка, то их нужно заключить в тег li, а в примере они находятся в ul - теге маркированного списка

Comment: незначительно, но список изменился

Comment: Остальное зависит уже от стилизации. Это лишь та ошибка, которую я заметил в разметке.